# A proof in Real Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

If we let $f$ be infinitely differentiable on an open interval $I$ containing the point $x=c$ and there exists a constant $M>0$ such that $|f^{(n)}(x)|\leq M$ for all $x\in I$ and all $n\geq0.$ I am trying to prove that,

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(c)}{n!}(x-c)^n$$

for all $x\in I$

I have an idea of what I need to do with this proof: in the question there is two conditions

1)$f(x)\in C^{\infty}$ on $(c-\sigma,c+\sigma)$
2)$|f^{(n)}x|\leq M$ for $x\in (c-\sigma,c+\sigma)$

So using the Taylor formula

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{k}\frac{f^n(c)}{n!}(x-c)^n+\frac{f^{(k+1)}(a)}{(k+1)!}a^{k+1}$$ for $a\in (c,x)$.

So if I can prove that $\frac{f^{(k+1)}(a)}{(k+1)!}a^{k+1}$ goes to $0$ then $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(c)}{n!}(x-c)^n$

So then when $k\to\infty$,

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{k}\frac{f^n(c)}{n!}(x-c)^n+\frac{f^{(k+1)}(a)}{(k+1)!}a^{k+1}\leq\frac{Ma^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}$$

So how can I show that $\frac{Ma^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}$ is monotonic and decreasing which should solve my proof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you actually have is that 
$$\left|f(x)-\sum_{n=0}^{k}\frac{f^n(c)}{n!}(x-c)^n\right|=\frac{M|a|^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}\leq\frac{M|x-c|^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}$$
The last bound is required since $a$ depends on both $x$ and $k$, which we want to avoid in the limiting process.

Now there are many ways to show that the last term tends towards zero. The first way that comes to mind is to use the ratio test to show that $\sum\frac{|x-c|^k}{k!}$ converges, hence *a fortiori* $\frac{|x-c|^k}{k!}\to 0$.

Comment: so I need to prove that $\frac{M|x-c|^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}$ tends to 0? and how would I use the ratio test on that?

Comment: @user123 Yep.  Just follow what I say in my last sentence for an easy way to do that.

Comment: so using the ratio test $\frac{|x-c|^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}\frac{k!}{|x-c|^k}$ = $\frac{|x-c|}{k+1}=0$? so it converges?

Comment: @user123 the last $=$ should be $\to$, but yes.

Comment: I actually had a typo in my answer for my question I meant to say $$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{k}\frac{f^n(c)}{n!}(x-c)^n+lim_{k->\infty}|\frac{f^{(k+1)}(a)}{(k+1)!}a^{n}|\leq\frac{Ma^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}$$ then prove that right post term approaches 0, does that make sense with that missing information?

Comment: @user123 That makes things more messy. You should have $$\lim_{k\to\infty}\left|f(x)-\sum_{n=0}^{k}\frac{f^n(c)}{n!}(x-c)^n\right|=\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{M|a|^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}\leq\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{M|x-c|^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}$$

Comment: okay thanks, final question then once I have proved that right most term approaches 0 by the ratio test as shown above then, $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(c)}{n!}(x-c)^n$?

Comment: @user123 Yep then you are done.

Comment: thanks for your help again

Answer (score 0):

HINT: essentially you must prove that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{c^n}{n!}=0,\quad \text{for any }c\in\Bbb R\tag{1}$$

and observe that if $|c|\le m$ for some $m\in \Bbb N$, then $|c|^n\le m^n$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$ from the axioms of an ordered field. Then if you prove that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{m^n}{n!}=0,\quad\text{for any }m\in\Bbb N\tag{2}$$

then using the squeeze theorem you will have that (2) implies (1).

> Let $f(n):=\frac{m^n}{n!}$, then $f(m+1)=f(m)\cdot\frac{m}{m+1}$. Hence $f(m+k)\le f(m)\left(\frac{m}{m+1}\right)^k$, and is clear that $\lim_{k\to\infty}\left(\frac{m}{m+1}\right)^k=0$ by the properties of an ordered field.